# Print out the error message from [error description]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

NSError *error ...

This is the result of `[error description]`:

[image]

I want to have just this message : `Another user is Already linked to this facebook id.`
Is there any way?

`[error localizeddescription]` is also print something else.

Comment: I do not see how this is related to Xcode...

Comment: Ok, I removed the `Xcode`, if it's fine with you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *description = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
```